# Issue to fadeout elements with jquery waypoints plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

as you can see on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZA8bd/4/) I'm trying to fade out elements when they enter viewport, using [waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started). Unfortunately this is not working - nothing fades out. Any idea why? Many thanks

CSS and HTML

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pre-block {
    background: green;
    width:90%;
    Height: 800px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.block {
    background: red;
    width:90%;
    Height: 200px;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
.c1 {
    background: #253151;
}
.c2 {
    background: #253151;
    border-left: 1px #FFF solid;
}
.c3 {
    background: #253151;
    border-left: 1px #FFF solid;
}
.c4 {
    background: #253151;
    border-left: 1px #FFF solid;
}


<div class="pre-block"></div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="col1 c1">dsqd</div>
    <div class="col2 c2">sdsqdss</div>
    <div class="col3 c3">sdqsdsq</div>
    <div class="col4 c4">sdsqd</div>
</div>
<script src="http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/jquery.js">
<script src="http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.js">
```

JS

```
$('.block').waypoint(function() {
   $(".col1").delay(10).fadeOut("slow");
   $(".col2").delay(20).fadeOut("slow");
   $(".col3").delay(30).fadeOut("slow");
   $(".col4").delay(40).fadeOut("slow");
}, { offset: 10 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided offset: 10 is not able to reach in fiddle.
Increase the offset and all is perfect.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why it is not working in live environment? See http://goo.gl/F8ciEs Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KkmQc/)

It works perfectly. I added an `alert('ok');` to the function and made the display iframe a bit smaller and I get the expected result:

[image: Expected output]

Maybe this offset would be better:

```
offset: $(window).height()
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why it is not working in live environment? See http://goo.gl/F8ciEs Many thanks

Comment: @Greg Because `400` is not enough. Make it bigger. For example `1000`. Or what is better use `$(window).height()` what I said before.

Comment: Thanks. Just updated the link but link doesn't work either. This is odd, would expect the col1, col2, etc to start fading out when the top of .block-left is 400px from the top of the viewport. Gosh, this is making me crazy

Comment: @Greg Then try `$(window).height()-400`.

Comment: Doesn't work either (link updated). I think I'll create a separate post for this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've found the solution! I moved the js code from the head section to before the body closing tag and now it works